# Asignación de un variable a un puntero dinámico

Tags: c, memoria

Tengo definido la variable compra como un puntero double:

```
double **compra = (double**)malloc(clientes * sizeof(char*));
```

tiene asignado el puntero clientes mediante asignación de memoria dinámica.

Después defino una variable double total

```
double total=compra[i]*0.80;
```

pero tira el siguiente error por no coincidencia de tipos en asignación

> error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'double *' and 'double')

¿Cómo se convierte correctamente compra para que coincidan los tipos en asignación?

Comment: `compra` es, a grandes rasgos, un arreglo de punteros, por ende, debes desreferenciar los valores, antes de poder usarlos. `double total=(*compra[i])*0.80;`

Comment: Si `compra` es un `double**`, sus elementos seran `double*`. O dereferencias los elementos de `compra`, o haces que `compra` sea un `double*` (No se si es posible, por la cantidad de codigo que compartes parece no tener sentido que sea un `double**`, pero falta el contexto del resto del codigo.).

Comment: Si queres te paso el programa completo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez no lo entiendes el error por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'double *' and 'double')

> error: operandos no válidos para * binario (tiene 'double *' y 'double')

El operador de multiplicación (`*` binario) requiere que los operandos sean compatibles entre si. A grandes rasgos, para que los operandos sean compatibles deben ser de tipo numérico, lo que no es tu caso ya que en un lado de la multiplicación tienes un dato de tipo puntero (`double *`) mientras que en e otro tienes un dato de tipo numérico (`dobule`):

```
//               _____ '0.80' es un literal de tipo 'double'
//              /
//             /
//           vvvv
   compra[i]*0.80;
// ^^^^^^^^^
//     \
//      \____ 'compra' es de tipo 'double **' por lo que 'compra[]' es de tipo 'double *'
```

> ¿Cómo se convierte correctamente compra para que coincidan los tipos en asignación?

No tienes que convertir nada, tienes que usar los tipos adecuados, posiblemente querías hacer esto:

```
double total=compra[i][x]*0.80;
//                    ~~~ <--- segundo nivel de datos
```

Comment: Igual la otra respuesta del usario me sirvió.